# About xmlrpc of objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-rpc

Recently I have been working about an iOS project.I want to send my picture to an server.I use xmlrpc to do this ,but when I write codes like this:

```
- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage ForName:(NSString *)imageName
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sourceImage);

    NSString  *imageString = [imageData base64EncodedString];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: SERVER_URL];  
    XMLRPCRequest *request = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc]
                              initWithURL:URL];

    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageName,imageString,nil];
    [request setMethod:@"upload_image" withParameter:params];
```

I give "imageName" to params,it will fail.But if I write code like this

```
- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage

{

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sourceImage);

    NSString  *imageString = [imageData base64EncodedString];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: SERVER_URL];  
    XMLRPCRequest *request = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc]
                              initWithURL:URL];
    NSString *imageName = @"hello.png";
    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageName,imageString,nil];
    [request setMethod:@"upload_image" withParameter:params];
```

It will be ok and I can upload the picture to the server.
I don't know why,can someone explain it ?

Comment: Are you failing with any sort of error? Does the variable `imageName` actually exist (and is non-nil) in the first version? Try inserting `NSLog(@"Image Name: %@", imageName);` before the last line in the first version see if it actually outputs what you expect.

Comment: I found the problem is the method "setMethod: withParameter".I changed it with "setMethod:withParameters" and it is OK,maybe the first method does not written right.